# JavaScript group by and count function

Tags: javascript, group-by

I use this function in JavaScript:

```js
function groupByAndCount(data, ...keys) {
  const {
    length
  } = keys;
  return Object.values(data[keys[0]].reduce((acc, _, i) => {
    const group = keys.map(key => data[key][i]);
    (acc[JSON.stringify(group)] ??= [...group, 0])[length]++;
    return acc;
  }, {}));
}

const data = {
  type: ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "b"],
  program: ["P1", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P1"],
  reference: ["ref1", "ref2", "ref3", "ref4", "ref5", "ref6", "ref7", "ref8"]
}

const result = groupByAndCount(data, "program", "type");
console.log(result);
```

It worked fine until today but now I get this error:

> ERROR: Unexpected token (5:38)

Do you know how to solve this? I don't understand it
I just understand that the "5" in "(5:38)" corresponds to the line 5:

```
(acc[JSON.stringify(group)] ??= [...group, 0])[length]++;
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the data format you expect to get back from `groupByAndCount()` ?

Comment: Your code as provided actually runs without an error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vjarmh?file=index.js.

Comment: Yes, to keep the example in the subject, I want to obtain this format : 
{
  "program": [
    "P1",
    "P2",
    "P1",
    "P2",
    "P2",
    "P1"
  ],
  "type": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "count": [
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1
  ]
}

Comment: Make sure you don't have any hidden characters in your code. When I put the code in a Stack Snippet and click the Tidy button, it separated the question marks. That could be due to the age of the code that runs the Tidy button (and it not knowing about `??=`), but it could be due to a zero-width space or something else.

Comment: The code you have runs fine with the dummy data. I would guess you have something in the data the causes `JSON.stringify(group)` to throw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ERROR: Unexpected token (5:38)" is referencing the Nullish coalescing assignment (??=) operator. The error suddenly popping up could be due to running the code in a different environment.

[This operator only assigns a value to a operand if that operand is null or undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment#syntax).

Try replacing the logic. It will look less beautiful but should work again.

```
if (!acc[JSON.stringify(group)]) {
    acc[JSON.stringify(group)] = [...group, 0];
}
acc[JSON.stringify(group)][length]++;
```

I have not tested it myself but it should work.